# Change a specific product button text in a Woocommerce product category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

How can I change the "Select Options" button to a "Buy Now" button for a specific variable product being shown on a specific archive category page in WooCommerce?

The Select Options button to be changed on the specific product category page:

[image: The Select Options button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will change the button from "Select options" to "Buy Now" for a specific product ID displayed on a specific product category archive page:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_loop_add_to_cart_button', 20, 2 ); 
function custom_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button_text, $product ) {
    // BELOW set the product categoty slug and the product ID
    if( is_product_category('clothing') && $product->get_id() == '40' ) {
        $button_text = __("Buy Now", "woocommerce");
    }
    return $button_text;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

HERE the product ID **`40`** is the 2nd one in the row on "clothing" product category page:

[image]

Comment: I failed to mention that the product is an Exteranl/Affiliate product and has a Product URL. Do you have the change of code that is needed for this? Thanks!